# Aws cloudwatch put-metric-data creating new metrics everytime instead of replacing the older one

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

**Exectation:**
I am trying to monitor the docker containers running on EC2 instance. For a simple use case, This is what I tried. Getting the number of container running in the machine using the simple bash script given bellow.

I will run this once working fine on cronjob such that it will count the container running and send the data to cloudwatch, every time it runs.

```
result=$(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | wc -l)
 aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name "Container running $result/6" --unit Count --value "$result" --dimensions Total-Container=$result --namespace System/Docker
```

**How Cloudwatch is behaving:**
Every time I run the job to check the number of containers running it is adding a new metrics. Now how can I track it in the graph.

[image]

> It might be the expected cloudwatch behavior but how do I track the
>   latest one in the graph.
>   Blockquote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are publishing a different metric name every time. The metric name is different because you include **$result** in the metric name.

A CloudWatch metric a time-ordered set of data points. A single metric is named/identified by 3 things:

- A Namespace (String)
- A Metric Name (String)
- Dimensions (Optional set of Key -> Value String pairs)

You can use these fields however you like. I'd suggest something like:

- Namespace: System/Docker
- Metric Name: e.g. NumContainersRunning
- Dimensions:

  - Maybe none?
  - Maybe something like Stage: Beta/Prod
  - Maybe something like Ec2InstanceId: BLA

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_concepts.html

If you want a metric to show how many containers are running across all your instances, you'll need to change your script to the following and deploy it on all your instances:

```
result=$(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | wc -l)
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name "NumContainersRunning" --unit Count --value "$result" --namespace System/Docker
```

Note: The metric name will be **NumContainersRunning**

If you want to have unique metric for every instance in your fleet, you'll need to publish a unique metric from each instance. You could do this by adding a dimension to the metric defining the instance id. This could be done with the following script:

```
instanceid=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
result=$(docker ps --format "{{.Names}}" | wc -l)
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --metric-name "NumContainersRunning" --unit Count --value "$result" --dimensions InstanceId=$instanceid --namespace System/Docker
```

Note: The metric name will still be **NumContainersRunning**. However, you will see different metrics on CloudWatch, one per instance.

On another note, have you considered using [Elastic Container Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/)? It will give you this metric and more right out of the box and save you needing to manage your containers manually.

Comment: Nicely explained. Thanks. Wish the documentation was similar.